# representation of $G$ on $F$

Tags: proof-verification, representation-theory

Given the representation $\rho: G\rightarrow GL(V)$ of the group $G$ on $F$. The dual representation is $\rho^* :G\rightarrow GL(V^*)$ with   $\rho^*  (g)f(v)=f(\rho(g^{-1})v)$.

I wanted to check that $\rho^*$ is a representation. So first I need to show that it is homomorphism.

Here is what I did but my result is not Ok! with what is expected.

For $g, h\in G$ and $f\in V^*$,\begin{align}\rho^*(gh)f(v)&=f(\rho(gh)^{-1}(v))\\&=f(\rho(h^{-1}g^{-1})(v))\\&=f(\rho(h^{-1})\rho(g^{-1})(v))\\&=\rho^*(h)f(\rho(g^{-1})(v))\\&=\rho^*(h)\rho^*(g)f(v)\end{align}

So I get $\rho^*(gh)=\rho^*(h)\rho^*(g)$,

Where did I made MISTAKE in showing homomorphism of $\rho^*$. Because the result is expected to be $\rho^*(gh)=\rho^*(g)\rho^*(h)$

Thank you

Comment: Your mistake is at the last step: $(\rho^*(h) f) (\rho(g)^{-1}v)) = ..$

Comment: I still don't understand how the arrangement is given that way. Sorry, it seems silly but it is something I should understand.

Comment: Ok I understand. So I should rewrite the representation for the dual this way                          $(\rho ^*(g)f)(v)=f(\rho(g^{-1})v)$. Am I correct now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that adding parenthesis will make things clearer:\begin{align}\bigl(\rho^*(gh)f\bigr)(v)&=f\bigl(\rho\bigl((gh)^{-1}\bigr)v\bigr)\\&=f\bigl(\rho\bigl(h^{-1}g^{-1}\bigr)v\bigr)\\&=f\bigl(\rho(h^{-1})\bigl(\rho(g^{-1})v\bigr)\bigr)\\&=\bigl(\rho^*(h)f\bigr)\bigl(\rho(g^{-1})(v)\bigr)\\&=\Bigl(\bigl(\rho^*(g)\bigr)\Bigl(\bigl(\rho^*(h)f\Bigr)\Bigr)(v)\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I  understand now where my problem is.